# Jquery Mouse Over Movement conflicting with other animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, slide

im currently working on my first website- but ive come to a slight problem with this piece of jquery... The page is:

http://beelinetest.site50.net/the_arts_and_culture_in_worcester.html

I have a rollover over effect throughout the completed pages on my website, (when you hover over the link, the word slightly moves to the right) this can be better seen on the events programme page.

But on this page ive got a lot of jquery going on... When clicked the word moves to the left off the page. But because of having the mouse over, (moving the word back to the right on release) the word shoots back on screen to its original place.

Please feel free to look into my code, id really appreciate it- i know you guys are great, so thanks in advance! Tom

Here are the two conflicting codes-

```
$("#exploretext").click(function(){ 
$(".moveeverythingleft").animate({"left":"-220px"}, 400);
return false;
});



$("#exploretext").hover(function(){ 
$("#exploretext").animate({"left":"227px"}, 50);
}, function(){
$("#exploretext").animate({"left":"217px"}, 150);
});
```

Comment: Could you paste the code that you think is causing the problem?

Comment: Have you tried e.stopPropagation(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will unbind your hover effect after a click event :

```
$("#exploretext").on("click",function() 
{ 
    $(this).off("hover", "**");
    $(".moveeverythingleft").animate({"left":"-220px"}, 400); return false; 
});

$("#exploretext").on('hover',function()
{ 
    $("#exploretext").animate({"left":"227px"}, 50); }, function()
    { 
        $("#exploretext").animate({"left":"217px"}, 150); 
    });
});
```

You may have to rebind it later, or to bind another, it depends on what you want to achieve.

It may be way easier to use another animate function, using += :

```
$("#exploretext").animate({"left":"+=10px"}, 50, 'linear');
```

**edit :**

I'm reading your code, the markup and the css is a bit of a mess, I think it makes your work harder than it should be.

I would advise you to try first to clean the HTML and the CSS, then to handle the JS part.

Answer (score 0):

what u can do is store the state of the button in some variable like ..

```
var position = "LEFT OR RIGHT";
```

then when u send the button to the left change the variable to left.
and in the hover event check the value and then if the position is left then dont execute whole of the event and if the position is right then execute the event.

```
function OnExploreClick(){
position = 'left';
//ur code
}

function OnUnExploreClick()
{
//put the button to right side// ur code
then position = 'right';
}
function OnHover()
{
if (position == 'right')
{
//execute ur code
}
}
```